# Can't understand function and reference behaviour

Tags: php

I have this code.

```
$add = (function () {
    $counter = 0;
    return function () use(&$counter) {return $counter += 1;};
})();

echo $add(); //1
echo $add(); //2
echo $add(); //3
```

Expected Output:

```
111
```

Original Output:

```
123
```

Inside the function `$counter=0` is assigned by 0 so the `&$counter` should be 0. 
So when i called it second time it sees `$counter=0` and so that `&$counter will be 0`, Isn't it?
Why it is incrementing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not call $counter=0 for the second time. You call it just once when initiating the first function. When you call $add(), you call every time the second function (that is in your return statement) which just uses the modified value of $counter that you passed by reference. If you would add `echo $counter;` after the `$counter = 0;` you will see that.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "sees"? The first time you execute `$add()`, the inner counter is counted up. As you used a **reference pointer** (through adding the ampersand in `use(&$counter)`) to the original `$counter`, this is also manipulated, so after executing this once, the counter variable no longer contains a zero.

When you remove that ampersand, the innermost function uses a fresh counter each and every time, such that your expected output is met

Comment: My main doubt is, i know that inside function variables are in local scope and after executing function those variables are removed. So when i called it second time, how the $counter have previous value!

Comment: What do you mean by "local scope"? Through passing `$counter` as a reference, you don't have two distinct variables called `$counter`, but only one. The second one is a pointer to the first

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass a reference to the function the initial `$counter = 0;` value is also increased each time you add 1 to it using `$counter += 1;` that's why your result is "123".

To get "111" you need to pass a variable to a function `$counter`, not a reference.